# ASPX Avoid page refresh after selectedindexchanged combobox without updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, updatepanel, postback

I am using a combobox on my website and when the `SelectedIndexChanged` event triggers, the page refreshes. I know you can prevent the page refresh with an `UpdatePanel` but I need another solution to prevent a page refresh.

Do you guys know any other solutions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not understanding what you are trying to accomplish.  The ComboBox will post back on the selection change if **AutoPostback=True**.  Set it to **False**.  Is there something else you are trying to do?

Comment: An example: I want to show the selected item (string) in a textbox, but the postback causes the page to refresh so the textbox is getting cleared

Comment: Edit your question to add more information on what you want to do.  Your example of setting the selected value into a textbox can be handled a couple of ways.  By supplying a better description of what you want done and what you have tried then we can provide a better answer on how to do it.

Comment: will it be an issue if you use javascript or Jquery to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

By your description in comments I think you want this. I´m using Jquery. This is a way to set value in textbox without to do postback.
Remember to set  **AutoPostback=false** in your DropDownList

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var slcLocationSelect = false;
    var slcSpecialtySelect = false;
    var slcGenderSelect = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").val($("#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>").val())
        });
    });
</script>
```